# Join elements of an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

Why  is my code not printing the joined array? With this code the array is printing the modified elements but not joined...

```
def translate(string)
    vowels=['a','e','o','u','i']
    string=string.split
    string.map! do
        |x| if vowels.include? x[0]
            x.insert(-1,'ay')
            else 
            x=x.slice(1, x.length)
            x=x.insert(-1, x[0]+'ay')
        end
    end
    string.join('-')
    print(string)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Array#join` method doesn't set itself as the joined string, instead it just returns a joined string. You can save the joined result into `string` itself like this:

```
# ...
string = string.join('-')
print string
```

Of course, use another variable can be more readable:

```
# ...
joined_string = string.join('-')
print joined_string
```

Comment: The method doesn't return the string it prints, so there's no reason to assign `string.join('-')` to a variable. `print string.join('-')` is sufficient (though `p` is probably more suitable than `print`).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for your comment. The variable `string` is actually an `Array` here. I've fix my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're not printing the value returned from the `join`.

```
joined = string.join('-')
print(joined)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not storing the value returned by `join` anywhere. `string` itself is still an Array. Try this instead:

```
print string.join('-')
```

Thus your method should look like:

```
 def translate(string)
    vowels=['a','e','o','u','i']
    string=string.split
    string.map! do
        |x| if vowels.include? x[0]
            x.insert(-1,'ay')
            else 
            x=x.slice(1, x.length)
            x=x.insert(-1, x[0]+'ay')
        end
    end
    print string.join('-')
 end
```